# Intersection of types as a result?

Tags: c#, generics, types

*For the record: union vs. intersection of types, see: [Advanced Types in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)*

Let's say I have interfaces `IA` and `IB`. It is very easy to create a intersection of those as parameter without creating extra interface.

```
void Foo<T>(T t) where T : IA, IB
```

However I cannot see a clear way to do the same when the result should be of intersection of types. Consider Provider/Factory scenario:

```
interface IProvider
{
  T Provide();
}
```

and later consumer will get this provider:

```
void Consume(IProvider provider)
```

The question is how to define `T`. If I define it making `Provide` method generic:

```
T Provide<T>() where ...
```

it does not make sense, because it would mean consumer somehow is able to tell already existing provider what type it provides.

If I define entire provider as generic type:

```
interface IProvider<T> where ...
{
  T Provide();
}
```

it makes more sense, but now the method `Consume` has to be generic as well and the need of defining generic constraints for union start "leaking" quickly making code ugly.

So is there a way to express it in clean manner and correctly? Exactly like when intersection was input -- short, clean and correct.

**Update:** as a workaround I use now type `Intersection` which provides type checking, however the price is extra memory consumption.

Comment: `where T : IA, IB` is the intersection of `IA` and `IB`.

Comment: What's bad in having empty extra interface? Is it unsuitable for some cases?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that types aren't sets, if a value is a member of type `IA` and type `IB`, then it's a member of the intersection of `IA` and `IB`. However in C# you can't give such relationships a name to refer to them later, so I think your only option is to make `Consume` generic and repeat the generic constraints on `T`.

Comment: @Seprum, yes, it leads to interfaces like `IAB`, then `IAC`, etc. Because you would have to introduce interface for each union you work on. I would like to avoid as well.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying but it's confusing because 'union of types' and 'intersection of types' has an existing meaning, and what you're describing is an intersection. See [here](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/types/) for example.

Comment: You may find this useful http://boustrophedonic.com/blog/2012/10/21/union-types-in-csharp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I'm sorry to tell you that what you're asking for — using an intersection type for a method return type — is simply not possible in C#. The type system is not sophisticated enough.

You might find my Software Engineering SE question ["Which statically typed languages support intersection types for function return values?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/136740/4906) of interest. I was surprised to learn that Java is superior to C# in that particular regard.

#### Intersection types ("both `A` and `B`") in C#:

- possible for method parameters using generics:

  ```
  void Method<T>(T parameter) where T : A, B
  ```
- not possible for method return types. (You could of course resort to late-bound tricks such as `dynamic` or creating a matching intersection type on the fly using `System.Reflection.Emit` / [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) (which is often used in mocking frameworks such as Moq to generate types on-the-fly); I am only looking at the possibilities of static typing / the type system in this answer.)

#### Union types ("either `A` or `B`") in C#:

- possible for method parameters using a variety of language mechanisms:

  - method overloads:

    ```
    void Method(A parameter);
    void Method(B parameter);
    ```
  - using implicit type conversions:

    ```
    struct AorB
    {
        public static implicit operator AorB(A a) { ... }
        public static implicit operator AorB(B b) { ... }
    }

    void Method(AorB parameter);
    ```
- can be faked for return values using some kind of generic, discriminated union-like type `Either<A, B>`.

Comment: Thank you, but as I understand it Java has the same limitations, it is up to caller to instantiate the method.